# trying to get user uid after creating account but getting null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the user uid after creating an account, so I can create a document on firestore with the uid as document id. The problem is that I get only null. Here's the function I am using:

```
void setUserDoc(name, lastName, email) {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> usersRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid);
  usersRef.set({
    'name': name,
    'lastName': lastName,
    'email': email,
    'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
  return;
}
```

and here is part of the widget:

```
Padding(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, right: 50, left: 50),
 child: ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
        _passwordError = validatePassword(passwordController.text);
        _emailError = validateEmail(emailController.text);
     });
     if (_passwordError == null && _emailError == null) {
     authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       emailController.text,
       passwordController.text,
    );
    setUserDoc(
      nameController.text,
      lastNameController.text,
      emailController.text,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
  }
},
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're accessing `auth.currentUser` before it's initialized, and then not handling the `null` it gives back well.

Since it takes time to restore the authentication state when the app starts, you should [listen to the auth state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state). With that, your code would be:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
      String? uid = user.uid;
      DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> usersRef =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid);
      usersRef.set({
        'name': name,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'email': email,
        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, i didn't think of it. I thought that after creating a new user i'd have had already the uid. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of creating an instance of `FirebaseAuth` `auth`, and trying to get the `uid` from it.

Instead you need to create an instance of `User` (earlier `FirebaseUser`) and then get the `uid` from it.

try this.

```
late User user;
String? uid;
void setUserDoc(name, lastName, email) {
  user= FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  uid = user.uid;
  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> usersRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid);
  usersRef.set({
    'name': name,
    'lastName': lastName,
    'email': email,
    'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
  return;
}
```